# How to Investigate and Optimize Performance for Parallel Processes (Calling API in Parallel)?

Tags: c#, wcf, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, task

I am trying to optimize a data collection process in C#. I would like to understand why a certain method of parallelism I am trying is not working as expected (more details below; see "Question" section at the very bottom)

###### BACKGROUND

I have an external .NET Framework DLL, which is an API for an external data source; I can only consume the API, I do not have access to what goes on behind the scenes.

The API provides a function like: `GetInfo(string partID, string fieldValue)`. Using this function, I can get information about a specific part, filtered for a single field/criteria. One single call (for just one part ID and one field value) takes around 20 milliseconds in an optimal case.

A part can have many values for the field criteria. So in order to get all the info for a part, I have to enumerate through all possible field values (13 in this case). And to get all the info for many parts (~260), I have to enumerate through all the part IDs and all the field values.

I already have all the part IDs and possible field values. The problem is performance. Using a serial approach (2 nested for-loops) is too slow (takes ~70 seconds). I would like to get the time down to ~5 seconds.

###### WHAT I HAVE TRIED

For different mediums of parallelizing work, I have tried:

- calling API in parallel via Tasks within a single main application.
- calling API in parallel via Parallel.ForEach within a single main application.
- Wrapping the API call with a WCF service, and having multiple WCF service instances (just like having multiple Tasks, but this is multiple processes instead); the single main client application will call the API in parallel through these services.

For different logic of parallelizing work, I have tried:

- experiment 0 has 2 nested for-loops; this is the base case without any parallel calls (so that's ~260 part IDs * 13 field values = ~3400 API calls in series).
- experiment 1 has 13 parallel branches, and each branch deals with smaller 2 nested for-loops; essentially, it is dividing experiment 0 into 13 parallel branches (so rather than iterating over ~260 part IDs * 13 field values, each branch will iterate over ~20 part IDs * all 13 field values = ~260 API calls in series per branch).
- experiment 2 has 13 parallel branches, and each branch deals with ALL part IDs but only 1 specific field value for each branch (so each branch will iterate over ~260 part IDs * 1 field value = ~260 API calls in series per branch).
- experiment 3 has 1 for-loop which iterates over the part IDs in series, but inside the loop makes 13 parallel calls (for 13 field values); only when all 13 info is retrieved for one part ID will the loop move on to the next part ID.

I have tried experiments 1, 2, and 3 combined with the different mediums (Tasks, Parallel.ForEach, separate processes via WCF Services); so there is a total of 9 combinations. Plus the base case experiment 0 which is just 2 nested for-loops (no parallelizing there).

I also ran each combination 4 times (each time with a different set of ~260 part IDs), to test for repeatability.

In every experiment/medium combination, I am timing only the direct API call using Stopwatch; so the time is not affected by any other parts of the code (like Task creation, etc.).

Here is how I am wrapping the API call in WCF service (also shows how I am timing the API call):

```
public async Task<Info[]> GetInfosAsync(string[] partIDs, string[] fieldValues)
{
   Info[] infos = new Info[partIDs.Length * fieldValues.Length]; 

   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < partIDs.Length; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < fieldValues.Length; j++)
         {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Restart();
            infos[i * fieldValues.Length + j] = api.GetInfo(partIDs[i], fieldValues[j]);
            timer.Stop();
            // log timer.ElapsedMilliseconds to file (each parallel branch writes to its own file)
         }
      }
   });

   return infos;
}
```

And to better illustrate the 3 different experiments, here is how they are structured. These are run from the main application. I am only including how the experiments were done using the inter-process communication (`GetInfosAsync` defined above), as that gave me the most significant results (as explained under "Results" further below).

```
// experiment 1
Task<Info[]>[] tasks = new Task<Info[]>[numBranches]; // numBranches = 13
for (int k = 0; k < numBranches; k++)
{
   tasks[k] = services[k].GetInfosAsync(partIDsForBranch[k], fieldValues); // each service/branch gets partIDsForBranch[k] (a subset of ~20 partIDs only used for branch k) and all 13 fieldValues
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks); // loop through each task.Result after WaitAll is complete to get Info[]
```

```
// experiment 2
Task<Info[]>[] tasks = new Task<Info[]>[fieldValues.Length];
for (int j = 0; j < fieldValues.Length; j++)
{
   tasks[j] = services[j].GetInfosAsync(partIDs, new string[] { fieldValues[j] }); // each service/branch gets all ~260 partIDs and only 1 unique fieldValue
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks); // loop through each task.Result after WaitAll is complete to get Info[]
```

```
// experiment 3
for (int i = 0; i < partIDs.Length; i++)
{
   Task<Info[]>[] tasks = new Task<Info[]>[fieldValues.Length];
   for (int j = 0; j < fieldValues.Length; j++)
   {
      tasks[j] = services[j].GetInfosAsync(new string[] { partIDs[i] }, new string[] { fieldValues[j] }); // each branch/service gets the currently iterated partID and only 1 unique fieldValue
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tasks); // loop through each task.Result after WaitAll is complete to get Info[]
}
```

###### RESULTS

For experiments 1 and 2...

- Task (within same application) and Parallel.ForEach (within same application) perform almost just like the base case experiment (approximately 70 to 80 seconds).
- inter-process communication (i.e. making parallel calls to multiple WCF services separate from the main application) performs significantly better than Task/Parallel.ForEach. This made sense to me (I've read about how multi-process could potentially be faster than multi-thread). Experiment 2 performs better than experiment 1, with the best experiment 2 run being around 8 seconds.

For experiment 3...

- Task and Parallel.ForEach (within same application) perform close to their experiment 1 and 2 counterparts (but around 10 to 20 seconds more).
- inter-process communication was significantly worse compared to all other experiments, taking around 200 to 300 seconds in total. **This is the result I don't understand** (see "What I Expected" section further below).

The graphs below give a visual representation of these results. Except for the bar chart summary, I only included the charts for inter-process communication results since that gave significantly good/bad results.

[image: experiments individual elapsed times]

- Figure 1 (above). Elapsed times of each individual API call for experiments 1, 2, and 3 for a particular run, for inter-process communication; experiment 0 is also included (top-left).

[image: summary and experiments aggregate elapsed times]

- Figure 2 (above). Summary for each method/experiment for all 4 runs (top-left). And aggregate versions for the experiment graphs above (for experiments 1 and 2, this is the sum of each branch, and the total time would be the max of these sums; for experiment 3, this is the max of each loop, and the total time would be the sum of all these maxes). So in experiment 3, almost every iteration of the outer loop is taking around 1 second, meaning there is one parallel API call in every iteration that is taking 1 second...

###### WHAT I EXPECTED

- The best performance I got was experiment 2 with inter-process communication (best run was around 8 seconds in total). Since experiment 2 runs were better than experiment 1 runs, perhaps there is some optimization behind-the-scenes on the field value i.e. experiment 1 could potentially have different branches clash by calling the same field value at any point in time, whereas each branch in experiment 2 calls their own unique field value at any point in time).
- I understand that the backend will be restricted by a certain number of calls per time period, so the spikes I see in experiments 1 and 2 make sense (and why there is almost no spikes in experiment 0).
- That's why I thought, for experiment 3 using inter-process communication, I am only making 13 API calls in parallel at any single point in time (for a single part ID, each branch having its own field value), and not proceeding to the next part ID until all 13 are done. This seemed like less API calls per time period than experiment 2, which continuously makes calls on each branch. So for experiment 3, I expected little spikes and all 13 to complete in the time it took for a single API call (~20ms).
- But what actually happened was that experiment 3 took the most time, and majority of API call times are spiking significantly (i.e. each iteration having a call taking around 1 second).
- I also understand that experiments 1 and 2 only have 13 long-lasting parallel branches that last throughout the lifetime of a single run, whereas experiment 3 creates 13 new short-lived parallel branches ~260 times (so there around be ~3400 short-lived parallel branches created throughout the lifetime of the run). If I was timing the task creation, I would understand the increased time due to overhead, but if I am timing the API call directly, how does this impact the API call itself?

###### QUESTION

Is there a possible explanation to why experiment 3 behaved this way? Or is there a way to profile/investigate this? I understand that this is not much to go off of without knowing what happens behind-the-scenes of the API... But what I am asking is how to go about investigating this, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your experiment 3 used two loops, and the object created in the loop will cause each loop to be created, increasing the workload.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Which object are you referring to?

Comment: The Tasks object in Experiment 3. The first two experiments had only one cycle, while the third experiment had twice as many cycles. I'm not sure if I'm accurate.